# EF Core LINQ use scalar function

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I use Entity Framework Core 2.1.

I have a scalar function in the database which adds specified number of days. 
I created an extension method to execute it:

```
public static class AdventureWorks2012ContextExt
    {
        public static DateTime? ExecFn_AddDayPeriod(this AdventureWorks2012Context db, DateTime dateTime, int days, string periodName)
        {
            var sql = $"set @result = dbo.[fn_AddDayPeriod]('{dateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")}', {days}, '{periodName}')";
            var output = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = @"result", DbType = DbType.DateTime, Size = 16, Direction = ParameterDirection.Output };
            var result = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(sql, output);
            return output.Value as DateTime?;
        }
    }
```

I try to use a scalar function in the query (to simplify things I use AdventureWorks2012) as follows:

```
var persons =
    (from p in db.Person
     join pa in db.Address on p.BusinessEntityId equals pa.AddressId
     where p.ModifiedDate > db.ExecFn_AddDayPeriod(pa.ModifiedDate, 100, "DayPeriod_day")
     select p).ToList();
```

But get an System.InvalidOperationException: 'A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.'

How can I achieve this?

**UPDATE:**
I managed to do it with the help of Ivan's answer:

```
var persons =
    (from p in db.Person
     join bea in db.BusinessEntityAddress on p.BusinessEntityId equals bea.BusinessEntityId
     join a in db.Address on bea.AddressId equals a.AddressId
     where p.ModifiedDate > AdventureWorks2012ContextFunctions.AddDayPeriod(a.ModifiedDate, 100, "DayPeriod_day")
     select p).ToList();
```

But now I need to update ModifiedDate for filtered persons. So I'm doing like this:

```
var persons =
     (from p in db.Person
      join bea in db.BusinessEntityAddress on p.BusinessEntityId equals bea.BusinessEntityId
      join a in db.Address on bea.AddressId equals a.AddressId
      let date = AdventureWorks2012ContextFunctions.AddDayPeriod(a.ModifiedDate, 100, "DayPeriod_day")
      where p.ModifiedDate > date
      select new { Person = p, NewDate = date }).ToList();

  foreach (var p in persons)
      p.Person.ModifiedDate = p.NewDate ?? DateTime.Now;

  db.SaveChanges();
```

But got System.NotSupportedException: 'Specified method is not supported.'

How can I use scalar function in select statement?

I tried to split the query by two parts:

```
var filteredPersons =                  // ok   
   (from p in db.Person
    join bea in db.BusinessEntityAddress on p.BusinessEntityId equals bea.BusinessEntityId
    join a in db.Address on bea.AddressId equals a.AddressId
    where p.ModifiedDate > AdventureWorks2012ContextFunctions.AddDayPeriod(a.ModifiedDate, 100, "DayPeriod_day")
    select new { Person = p, a.ModifiedDate }).ToList();

var persons =                          // here an exception occurs
    (from p in filteredPersons
     select new { Person = p, NewDate = AdventureWorks2012ContextFunctions.AddDayPeriod(p.ModifiedDate, 100, "DayPeriod_day") }).ToList();
```

Comment: Can `fn_AddDayPeriod` be modified to accept `datetime` instead of `varchar` (or whatever text type it's using currently)?

Comment: fn_AddDayPeriod is quite complicated function. That's why I wanted to call it directly.

Comment: fn_AddDayPeriod has three parameters which have DATETIME, INT and VARCHAR(100) types. I shouldn't modify this function.

Comment: Ah, so it's already `datetime`, perfect. Can we modify the `AdventureWorks2012Context` class or that's not allowed?

Comment: Yes, we can modify the db context.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of invoking the function client side (which is this particular case happens as part of the [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) of the query filter, while the query reading is still in progress), you can use EF Core [Database scalar function mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.0#database-scalar-function-mapping) so it

> can be used in LINQ queries and translated to SQL.

One way to do that is to create a public static method in the derived context class and mark it with `DbFunction` attribute:

```
public partial class AdventureWorks2012Context
{
    [DbFunction("fn_AddDayPeriod")]
    public static DateTime? AddDayPeriod(DateTime dateTime, int days, string periodName) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

and use

```
where p.ModifiedDate > AdventureWorks2012Context.AddDayPeriod(pa.ModifiedDate, 100, "DayPeriod_day")
```

Another way is to create a public static method in another class

```
public static class AdventureWorks2012DbFunctions
{
    [DbFunction("fn_AddDayPeriod")]
    public static DateTime? AddDayPeriod(DateTime dateTime, int days, string periodName) => throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

but then you'll need to register it with fluent API (which happens automatically for methods defined inside the context derived class):

```
modelBuilder
    .HasDbFunction(() => AdventureWorks2012DbFunctions.AddDayPeriod(default(DateTime), default(int), default(string)));
```

The usage is the same:

```
where p.ModifiedDate > AdventureWorksDbFunctions.AddDayPeriod(pa.ModifiedDate, 100, "DayPeriod_day")
```

Comment: Hi, Ivan, I updated my question. Can you please have a look at it?

Comment: Hi, normally it should work in select (and any other) clause of the query, so I'm not sure what's going on here - looks like some client evaluation is hitting our `throw new NotSupportedException();` code. Can you verify that by putting breakpoint on it?

Comment: I've disabled client evaluation, an exception still occurs on the line public static DateTime? AddDayPeriod(DateTime dateTime, int days, string periodName) => throw new NotSupportedException();

Comment: Yeah, I've verified that as well. Our implementation works only when translated to SQL, and under some circumstances EF Core is trying to evaluate it locally. The best you can do is to provide the C# client implementation of the method instead of throwing not supported exception.

Comment: As of EF Core 2.1 the function can be declared as a member function of your derived DbContext.